# If $\sigma \in Aut(G)$where $|G|$ odd has order 2 there exists Sylow $p$-subgroup with $\sigma(P)=P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of odd order and $\sigma$ an automorphism of G of order 2. Show that if the prime $p$ divides $|G|$ then there exist a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ such that $\sigma(P)=P$.

Comment: Hint: the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups divides $|G|$, so it is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ denote the set of all Sylow $p$ subgroups. Then $|S|$ divides $|G|$, and so $|S|$ is odd. Obviously, $\sigma$ induces an automorphism of sets from $S$ to itself by $P\mapsto\sigma(P).$ Since $\sigma$ has order $2$, this automorphisms divides $S$ into orbits of size $1$ or $2$. Since $|S|$ is odd, there must be an orbit of size $1$, which is a $P\in S$ with $\sigma(P)=P$.